# Changing HTML tag after two index while Mapping an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Lets say I have array of images(URL)

```
const images = ["image", "image", "image", "image"]
```

I want to map this array and render in react like this:-

```
      <div className="left">
        <img src={images[0]} />
        <img src={images[1]} />
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <img src={images[2]} />
        <img src={images[3]} />
      </div>
```

I was thinking about doing odd even concept but I won't work that way.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it matter to you which two images are in the "left" div and which are in the "right" div?

Comment: Yes, as the images are coming from db and I wanted to arrange in sequence wise @BlunderingPhilosopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap after two index to which array to push to like this:

```
const images = ["image", "image", "image", "image"];
const leftItems = [], rightItems = [];
let countToShift = 1, arrayToPushTo = leftItems;
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   arrayToPushTo.push(images[i]);
   if(countToShift === 2) {
       arrayToPushTo = (arrayToPushTo === leftItems) ? rightItems : leftItems;
       countToShift = 1;
   } else {
       countToShift++;
   }
}
```

Comment: There are odd index also in left part, which cannot be achieved by doing this. I already thought about this.

Comment: @ShubhamAmbastha, I have updated my answer please check now.

Comment: It works, but now i changed my approach. Btw thanks

Comment: Ohhhh.... I guess I got a bit late in finding the solution then. Btw thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You may loop through the `images` array and prepare two sections of `leftItems` and `rightItems` as below:

```
const images = ["image", "image", "image", "image"]

  const leftItems = []
  const rightItems = []

  for (const [index, value] of images.entries()) {
    if(index % 2 === 0){
       leftItems.push(<img key={index} src={value} />)
    } else {
       rightItems.push(<img key={index} src={value} />)

  }

  return (
    <div className="left">
      {leftItems}
    </div>
    <div className="right">
      {rightItems}
    </div>

  )
```

Comment: What if i don't want to change change image position. Like in my question there is image with index 0 and 1 in left & index 2 and 3 in right, that means odd and even both